# Adding blank rows to a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following 2d array in Java set to a variable named myMap:

```
1 3 1
3 2 3
1 3 1
```

The next step in my program is to add rows and columns of zeros as follows:

```
1 0 3 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
3 0 2 0 3
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 3 0 1
```

Basically, I'm adding arrays of zero into the spaces between the previous rows/columns. I then fill them in with appropriate numbers (irrelevant to my question) and repeat the process (adding more rows/columns of zeros) a finite number of times.

My question is as follows- what is the easiest and most efficient way to do this in Java? I know I could create a new 2d array and copy everything over, but I feel like there may be a more efficient way to do this. My intuition says that a 2d ArrayList may be the better way to go.

Also, and this my be important, when my program begins, I DO know what the maximum size this 2d array. Also, I cannot expect the symmetry of the numbers that I put in for this example (these were just put in for a good visual reference).

Comment: ArrayList would be slower; use an array. ArrayLists have to resize, unless you set their size... in which case you have an array, so it's the same thing.

Comment: Speed or efficiency would not factor into my decision.  I would do this in the way that is the easiest and least error-prone.  I'd use an ArrayList of ArrayLists, probably wrapped in a class that abstracts the 'insert columns' and 'insert rows' tasks.

Comment: If memory is not a question, you could simply use an array with max size, and keep the size of the matrix somewhere else (e.g. if it's 3 your loops only go to 3, even thought the actual array is 10x10)

Comment: if speed and efficiency are not factors to your decision, you should remove "most efficient way" from your question ;-)

Comment: Efficiency is most definitely a factor in my decision. I'm going to be preforming this operation many MANY times, and want it to go as quickly as possible, especially when the matrix gets to very large sizes.

Comment: Oh sry, I thought Tony Ennis comment was from you.

Comment: I am indeed a student, but what I am doing has nothing to do with my studies. I'm trying to come up with my own program to run the Square-Diamond Algorithm in order to generate random looking terrain. Purely for my own entertainment, as I'm interested in procedural generation, and this algorithm was stated (by a member of SO) as a good starting point.

Comment: You just need to add rows or columns too?

Comment: Do you know how many rows of zeros you'll have to add before you start adding them?

Comment: Both! I need zero rows AND columns.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking Edd, but the final size of the matrix will always be square and always have a length of (2^n +1), where the user is prompted for "n" before anything starts.

Comment: @nobillygreen post "at<SO_nickname>" to send the comment to that person.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for the advice :) Still new to SO, so I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Please, add "and columns" to the question's title. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with ArrayLists: (test included)

```
    int[][] ar = new int[][]
        {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8 } };
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>(ar.length);
    ArrayList<Integer> blankLine = new ArrayList<>(ar.length * 2 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length * 2 - 1; i++)
    {
        blankLine.add(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> line = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++)
        {
            line.add(ar[i][j]);
            if (j != ar[i].length - 1)
                line.add(0);
        }
        a.add(line);
        if (i != ar.length - 1)
            a.add(blankLine);
    }

    for (ArrayList<Integer> b : a)
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[6, 0, 7, 0, 8]
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you so much for the help, Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

- **Algorithm**

  ```
  int[][] appendRows(int[][] bag, int[]... rows) {
      int[][] extendedBag = new int[bag.length + rows.length][];
      int i = 0;
      for (int[] row : bag)  { fillRow(extendedBag, row, i++); }
      for (int[] row : rows) { fillRow(extendedBag, row, i++); }
      return extendedBag;
  }

  // WHERE #fillRow(int[][], int[], int) =

  void fillRow(int[][] bag, int[] row, int i) {
      bag[i] = new int[row.length];
      System.arraycopy(row, 0, bag[i++], 0, row.length);
  }
  ```
- **Demo**

  ```
  import java.util.Arrays;                                                              

  /** Utilities for 2D arrays. */
  public class Array2dUtils {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int[][] bag = new int[][] {
                  { 0 },
                  { 1, 1 },
                  { 2, 2, 2 }
          };
          int[] row1 = new int[] { 3, 3};
          int[] row2 = new int[] { 4 };

          int[][] biggerBag = appendRows(bag, row1, row2);

          System.out.println("Bag:\n" + toString(bag));
          System.out.println("Bigger Bag:\n" + toString(biggerBag));
      }

      /** Append one or more rows to a 2D array of integers. */
      public static int[][] appendRows(int[][] bag, int[]... rows) {
          int[][] extendedBag = new int[bag.length + rows.length][];

          int i = 0;
          for (int[] row : bag)  { fillRow(extendedBag, row, i++); }
          for (int[] row : rows) { fillRow(extendedBag, row, i++); }

          return extendedBag;
      }

      /* fill i-th item of the bag */
      private static void fillRow(int[][] bag, int[] row, int i) {
          bag[i] = new int[row.length];
          System.arraycopy(row, 0, bag[i++], 0, row.length);
      }

      /** Pretty-prints a 2D array of integers. */
      public static String toString(int[][] bag) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (int i = 0; i < bag.length; ++i) {
              sb.append(Arrays.toString(bag[i])).append("\n");
          }
          return sb.toString();
      }
  }
  ```

---

```
$ javac Array2dUtils.java
$ java -cp "." Array2dUtils
Bag:
[0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]

Bigger Bag:
[0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3]
[4]
```